# Asp.net MVC3 Help regarding URL's

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am making an application using Asp.net MVC,

I have a url which is generating dynamically like
http:\localhost:4351\username

I want the functionality that if a user copy it on address bar it'llredirect to a new address
 like

http:\localhost:4355\users\profile\username

I've a controller named users and an action named profile defined in it

How can i implement this functionality?

Comment: How do you distinguish an URL you generated (and that is visible by the user) like 'http:\localhost:4351\username' from an URL 'http:\localhost:4355\users\profile\username' that directly input by the user in the address bar?

Comment: The Generated URL and the URL visible to user are both the same,ie i'm displaying the generated URL and user can copy it and paste it on address bar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two MapRoutes.

It's unclear if you meant "username" to be the actual user's name or part of the URL. So I will show both ways:

Method 1:

This is if your path is literal: http:\localhost:4351\username
and literal path: http:\localhost:4355\users\profile\username

```
routes.MapRoute("Route1", "Username", new { controller = "Users", action = "Profile" });
routes.MapRoute("Route2", "Users\Profile\Username", new { controller = "Users", action = "Profile" });
```

If username is meant to be the users actual name, then do this:

Method 2:

Example:  http:\localhost:4351\mySpecialUsername
and http:\localhost:4351\users\profile\mySpecialUsername

```
routes.MapRoute("Route1", "{Username}", new { controller = "Users", action = "Profile" });
routes.MapRoute("Route2", "Users/Profile/{Username}", new { controller = "Users", action = "Profile" });
```

For Method 2, your action in your controller should look like this:

```
// Example
public ActionResult Profile(string Username)
{
    return Content(string.Format("Username: {0}", Username));
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add roure to the Global.asax.cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "UsernameRoute", // Route name
                "{username}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Redirect" } 
            );
```

And add the following action to the HomeController:

```
 public ActionResult Redirect(string username)
        {
            //Check if user exists
            bool userExists = true;
            if (userExists)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Profile", "User", new { id = username });
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but when i type http:\\localhost:4351\username it is showing error msg


The IControllerFactory 'MyApplication.Web.Mvc.SpringControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'username'.